# How to let Ruby-Gnuplot/Multiplot plot to file?

Tags: ruby, gnuplot

The example

```
require 'gnuplot'
require 'gnuplot/multiplot'
def sample
    x = (0..50).collect { |v| v.to_f }
    mult2 = x.map {|v| v * 2 }
    squares = x.map {|v| v * 4 }

    Gnuplot.open do |gp|
        Gnuplot::Multiplot.new(gp, layout: [2,1]) do |mp|
            Gnuplot::Plot.new(mp) { |plot| plot.data << Gnuplot::DataSet.new( [x, mult2] ) }
            Gnuplot::Plot.new(mp) { |plot| plot.data << Gnuplot::DataSet.new( [x, squares] ) }
        end
    end
end
```

works pretty well. But how can I send this to a file instead of the screen? Where to put `plot.terminal "png enhanced truecolor"` and `plot.output "data.png"`?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, I don't even know where I should call `#terminal` and `#output` methods since the plot object are inside a multiplot block.

As a workaround, the following would work as expected.

```
Gnuplot.open do |gp|
   ...
end
```

The block parameter `gp` in this part is passed the IO object to send the command to gnuplot through the pipe. Thus, we can send commands ("set terminal", "set output") directly to gnuplot via `gp`.

```
    Gnuplot.open do |gp|
        gp << 'set terminal png enhanced truecolor' << "\n"
        gp << 'set output "data.png"' << "\n"
        Gnuplot::Multiplot.new(gp, layout: [2,1]) do |mp|
            Gnuplot::Plot.new(mp) { |plot| plot.data << Gnuplot::DataSet.new( [x, mult2] ) }
            Gnuplot::Plot.new(mp) { | plot| plot.data << Gnuplot::DataSet.new( [x, squares] ) }
        end
    end
```